# SQL Navigator throws 'ORA-01834: Not a valid month' but query runs in other applications

Tags: oracle, sql-navigator

I have stocked in this error many times but know I have no way to avoid and I have to get rid of it.

Sometimes I do run a query in `SQL Navigator 6.1 XPert Edition` and it throws:

`ORA-01843: Not a valid month`

But if I run this same query in same database but in other application(ie `Aqua Data Studio`) it works fine. It's just in isolated cases.

It may be some config problem?

**EDIT: This query has that problem:**

```
            select
                quantity dias_a_vencer
                , estab
                , initcap (planejador) planejador
                , atributo2 fabrica
                , mrp.item montagem
                , initcap (descricao) des_montagem
                , mrp.nro_docmto num_of
                , initcap (mrp.fornecedor) cliente
                , mrp.project_number projeto
                , initcap (comprador) processista
                , trunc (mrp.data_inicio) data_inicio
            from etlt_mrp_exceptions mrp
            where 
                mrp.compile_designator = 'ENGI'
                and mrp.dt_coleta > sysdate - 50
                and estab = '179'        -- PARAMETRO ESTAB FILTRO
                and atributo2 = '11'   -- PARAMETRO FABRICA FILTRO
                and nvl (mrp.quantity, 0) > 0
                and dt_coleta = '05/12/2011'                         -- parametro do grafico acima
                and initcap (planejador) = 'Maria Cristina Da Cruz Costa'        -- parametro do grafico acima
            order by quantity
            , des_montagem
```

Comment: @Ben When a got this error, even a simple `select * from ...` throws it!!

Comment: somuser2 has it right. I believe Oracle's date format by default is DD-MON-YY  so '28-JAN-2010'.  If your date isn't in that format Oracle by default will not accept it, so recast it to the format you provided.  Other applications may implicitly recognize 28/01/2010 but Oracle does not.  Plus there's added confusion when you hit dates such as 1/1/2010 is it M/D/Y format or D/M/Y?

Comment: Is not a query error, not a database error. It is an error of `SQL Navigator`. In other applications the queries run ok!! The problem is the format that navigator doesn't understand. I'll not change my queries cause in my `php` app it runs ok.

Comment: @Márcio: it's not an error in SQL Navigator. It most definitely is a problem with implicit conversion from a string to a date in **your** query. Please post your query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Like I said to Ben I've already got this error on an simple `select * ` !!

Comment: @Márcio: prove it by showing that simple query!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've founded the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your query fail-safe in **all** environments, you have to change this line:

```
and dt_coleta = '05/12/2011'
```

to

```
and dt_coleta = to_date('05/12/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Assuming that you meant December 5th, and not May, 12th.

Btw: what datatype are the columns `estab` and `atributo2`. If those are numbers you should remove the single quotes around the parameters. That is another "implicit" data conversion that would e.g. prevent the usage of an index on those columns.

Comment: Thei're are `numbers` I think, cause I have no access to it, it's a `view`. Anyway, thank you for you explanation, I'll give more attention to that.

Answer (score 1):

Always specify a date format, never assume it or use default formats.  For example:

```
insert into mytable (mydate) values (to_date('02/28/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even using TO_DATE() does not guarantee success. (But I would strongly recommend that you are *always* aware of the date format in play.)  For instance using SQL*Developer, this works:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss.ddd';

select * from nns.nns_logGER WHERE LOG_DATE >= '2014-jul-30 14:47:16.211';
```

but this fails with "ORA-01834: day of month conflicts with Julian date" error:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss.ddd';

select * from nns.nns_logGER WHERE LOG_DATE >= '2014-jul-30 14:47:16.210';
```

Notice that I changed only the last digit.  And using to_date did not help:

```
select * from nns.nns_logGER WHERE LOG_DATE >= 
to_date('2014-jul-30 14:47:16.210','yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss.ddd');
```

fails in the same way.

I wish there were better news, but I think this must be some internal problem.